# Unable to open ISO file by using WinRAR

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

Am using windows7, am trying to open a ISO file by using WINRAR but am getting a error no archives found?, and ISO file contains 5gb of data.Can you please tell me how to open that file?

Comment: Have you tried mounting your ISO to a virtual CD drive?

Comment: I tried but that is also not working.

Comment: 7-Zip can also open ISO files. I wonder though whether the ISO is corrupt, or protected in some way.

Comment: Is there a way to verify the ISO file's integrity (e.g., an MD5 or SHA1 hash) from its source?

Comment: If you're having trouble opening it then it's probably a corrupt ISO file.  The two tools I use are MagicDisc and Pismo File Mount Audit Package - try those, if they don't open it, then it's a bad or misnamed file.

Comment: Am trying to mount image with Power ISO Getting an error File format is invalid or unsupported.And when am extracting the file using Power ISO the window is disappearing.

Comment: the file is corrupted.

Comment: If WinRAR is unable to extract the contents of the ISO then its not a proper ISO.  two ways you can handle this.  Extract the data and create a proper ISO, or simply Extract the data, using some other program.

Answer (score 1):

It could be in another format, and just named `.iso`. Try renaming it to `.zip`, `.rar` or `.7z`, and opening it with the appropriate program.

If neither work, try looking at the first few bytes in a hex-editor. Some file-formats have a few characters [identifying the file format](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html).

ISO-files usually begin with a lot of `00 00 00 00 ...` (zero-bytes)

Comment: If the file is an image of a disc, but it's not a data CD-ROM or DVD-ROM, then I don't believe WinRAR (or 7-zip) can deal with it.  I think I've encountered this with rips of VCDs and game discs before.

Comment: This does not really solve anything.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an image of a DVD or CD. Try using this [tool](http://www.filehippo.com/download_daemon_tools/).
Also, even if it's not, do give it a shot, it would probably work!

Hope it helps.

**Update**

1. The tool is called `'Daemon Tools LITE'`, it is freeware.
2. Once you install it; go to the notification area on the windows taskbar.
3. Single Click on the Daemon Tools Icon (Icon = Thunder lightning), click on '[G:]No Media' > MOUNT> another window pops up, browse to the location of your `.iso` file, select it.
4. Once it is done, a new CD-Drive by the name of your ISO will be shown in 'My Computer'.

Comment: Please add some mor informations to your answer. Also call the tool by name. Because, if the website changes the domain nobody will know, what the tool is called.(DAEMON Tools Lite)

Comment: Will this work? @c0dev

Comment: Yes. Great. I've formatted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this happens when there is an error, or a direct stop, or something blocks the file from being downloaded.

This causes the file to be corrupted. The only way to solve is this is to re-download it and try to not close the computer. I am also facing the problem, and I am not ready to download the file of 4.37 GB again.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  The only part that deals with solving the problem is "to re-download it", which is generic advice and won't necessarily help if there is an underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file in 7-zip. 7zip can treat so many types of files as archives if they contain such data.

If it doesn't work, your download was interrupted. You'll need to download the file again.